# EntityFrameworkCore with Mysql

Tags: mysql, entity-framework

I am using Identity and Entity Framework using Mysql. When I run the command

```
  dotnet ef database update
```

I get the following error.

> The entity type 'HistoryRow' requires a primary key to be defined.

**Context File**

```
            public class ApplicationDbContext :    IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
     {
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        // modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ProductVersion).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.Id).HasMaxLength(127));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity => entity.Property(m => m.Id).HasMaxLength(127));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(127);
            entity.Property(m => m.ProviderKey).HasMaxLength(127);
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(127);
            entity.Property(m => m.RoleId).HasMaxLength(127);
        });
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(m => m.UserId).HasMaxLength(127);
            entity.Property(m => m.LoginProvider).HasMaxLength(127);
            entity.Property(m => m.Name).HasMaxLength(127);
        });
    }
}
```

If I set **MigrationId** as the primary key through fluent API as

```
modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().HasKey(h => h.MigrationId)
```

Then it gives error something like

> You can't set primary key to 'HistoryRow' because it is not accessible

**StartUp.cs**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseMySQL("Server=localhost;port=3306;database=netcore;uid=root;Password=password"));


        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        services.AddMvc();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, AuthMessageSender>();
        services.AddTransient<ISmsSender, AuthMessageSender>();

        services.AddIdentityServer()
              .AddTemporarySigningCredential()
              .AddInMemoryScopes(Config.GetScopes())
              .AddInMemoryClients(Config.GetClients())
              .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>();
    }
```

> I am using SapientGuarden.EntityFrameWork.MySql Package